# how to populate keystoneJS relationship

Tags: keystonejs

in keystoneJs's doc:
Populating related data in queries

You can populate related data for relationship fields thanks to Mongoose's populate functionality. To populate the author and category documents when loading a Post from the example above, you would do this:

```
Post.model.findOne().populate('author categories').exec(function(err,post) {
    // the author is a fully populated User document
    console.log(post.author.name);
});
```

my question is that there is any options I can configure so these List APIs can populate the many relationship automatically.

thanks.

mike so

Answer (score 1):

I think not. This is how I do it when I use Keystone as an API (using .populate).

```
exports.getStoreWithId = function (req, res) {
Store.model
    .find()
    .populate('productTags productCategories')
    .where('_id', req.params.id)
    .exec(function (err, item) {
        if (err) return res.apiError('database error', err);
        res.apiResponse({
            store: item,
        });
    });
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the short answer here is no. If you want to populate you'll need to include the `.populate`.

That being said, keystone gives you access to the mongoose schema, so the answer here should work. Obviously their `mongoose.Schema` is done by your `Post.add` stuff so I think you can ignore their first snippet, and you should be able to add the hooks as `Post.schema.pre(...` for the second snippet.

The `Post.schema.pre('save',...` hooks definitely work with keystone, so I assume the pre-find hooks work too, however I've not actually tested this. (I'd be interested to know the outcome though!)

Finally, if that works, you could also have a look at the [mongoose-autopopulate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate) package, and see if you can get that to play nicely with keystone.